How to add \dotfill in a merged cell in tabularray
I'm having problem adding \dotfill to a merged cell in tabularray.
I tried:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{fontsize}

\geometry{ a4paper, left=20mm, right=20mm, bottom=20mm, top=20mm }

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
        width=\linewidth,
        colspec={|X[l,m]|X[l,m]|X[l,m]|X[l,m]|}
    }
    \hline
    item 1 & spec 1-1 \dotfill & spec 1-2 \dotfill & $\Box$ \\
    \hline
    item 2 & spec 2-1 \dotfill & spec 2-2 \dotfill & $\Box$ \\
    \hline
    item 2 & \SetCell[c=2]{}spec 3\dotfill & & $\Box$ \\
    \hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}


But the merged cell does not display the dots (see the screenshot). How do I make it work?


The log shows:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./merge-cell.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tabularray/tabularray.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontsize/fontsize.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xfp/xfp.sty))
(./merge-cell.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
Overfull \hbox (21.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 25--26
[][] 
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./merge-cell.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)</usr/share/texlive/texmf-d
ist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fon
ts/type1/public/amsfonts/symbols/msam10.pfb>
Output written on merge-cell.pdf (1 page, 20113 bytes).
Transcript written on merge-cell.log.


Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you get an error message? Which one first?

@Mensch I added the output of the pdflatex command. But I'm not sure if there is an error there.

Well, TeX Live 2022 is a little bit outdated. Is it possible to update it?

@Mensch Isn't the result the same in TL2024?

@Mensch I'm afraid not. I'm using ubuntu 22.04 and this seem to be the latest version I can update with apt.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I don't know, I'm using MikTeX...

@Mensch Ok, but doesn't an up-to-date miktex also reproduce the problem?

This issue is documented in the section 3.1.4, Hspan and Vspan Algorithms, of the tabularray package.

With hspan=default or hspan=even, tabularray package will compute column widths from span widths. But with hspan=minimal, it will compute span widths from column widths.

In your case, you need hspan=minimal to set the merged cell width to be the total width of the two cells.
Example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{fontsize}

\geometry{ a4paper, left=20mm, right=20mm, bottom=20mm, top=20mm }

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  width=\linewidth,
  colspec={|X[l,m]|X[l,m]|X[l,m]|X[l,m]|},
  hspan=minimal
  }
  \hline
  item 1 & spec 1-1 \dotfill & spec 1-2 \dotfill & $\Box$ \\
  \hline
  item 2 & spec 2-1 \dotfill & spec 2-2 \dotfill & $\Box$ \\
  \hline
  item 2 & \SetCell[c=2]{} spec 3\dotfill  & & $\Box$ \\
  \hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}



Awesome, this works very well. I marked it as the answer.

@Rekkhan As pointed by Tim funke's answer you need to set the cell width. It's what do automatically hspan=minimal.

You have to set the mandatory width parameter of SetCell to the expected width of the cell. So replacing the last line of the table:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{fontsize}

\geometry{ a4paper, left=20mm, right=20mm, bottom=20mm, top=20mm }

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
        width=\linewidth,
        colspec={|X[l,m]|X[l,m]|X[l,m]|X[l,m]|}
    }
    \hline
    item 1 & spec 1-1 \dotfill & spec 1-2 \dotfill & $\Box$ \\
    \hline
    item 2 & spec 2-1 \dotfill & spec 2-2 \dotfill & $\Box$ \\
    \hline
    item 2 & \SetCell[c=2]{0.5\columnwidth}spec 3\dotfill & & $\Box$ \\   % <-- Added column width
    \hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}

shows the \dotfill as expected:


Please add an complete code with your solution for an fast proof!

Thank you very much, this work, but I mark the @jlab's solution the right answer. Yours requires computing the new column width, which may cause issue when the table is resized.

You are right, @Rekkhan, this is definitely a more elegant solution that I would prefer, too.

Thanks, @Mensch, I've replaced the single changed line with the complete file for fast proofing.
